# How to add rows and columns to an outcome got by table() function

Tags: r, dplyr, addition

I have the following dataset:

I have been trying to build a contingency table, by using the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data1 %>% 
  select(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %>% 
  group_by(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %$% 
  with(., table(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant)) 


, , participant = pilot01

                        trial_resp.corr
blockLabel                0  1
  auditory_only           0 12
  bimodal_focus_auditory  1 71
  bimodal_focus_visual    3 69
  divided                74 70
  visual_only             0 12

, , participant = pilot02

                        trial_resp.corr
blockLabel                0  1
  auditory_only           0 12
  bimodal_focus_auditory  1 71
  bimodal_focus_visual    2 70
  divided                77 67
  visual_only            11  1

, , participant = pilot03

                        trial_resp.corr
blockLabel                0  1
  auditory_only           1 11
  bimodal_focus_auditory  1 71
  bimodal_focus_visual    3 69
  divided                75 69
  visual_only             0 12
```

What I would like to do is to add a further column with values (under 1 and 0) converted in percentage and a final with the Total.

I do not know whether it is possible, but if not, please suggest some iterative ways (do.call(), apply(), map(), for loop) to do this if the first way is not possible.

I have used the following solution but I do not how to move on

```
data1%>%  select(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %>% 
  group_by(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %$% 
  as.data.frame(with(., table(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant))) %>% 
  mutate(freq = Freq / sum(Freq)) %>% 
  group_split(participant, trial_resp.corr)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq    freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
1 auditory_only          0               pilot01         0 0      
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0               pilot01         1 0.00107
3 bimodal_focus_visual   0               pilot01         3 0.00321
4 divided                0               pilot01        74 0.0791 
5 visual_only            0               pilot01         0 0      

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq   freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>  <dbl>
1 auditory_only          1               pilot01        12 0.0128
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 1               pilot01        71 0.0759
3 bimodal_focus_visual   1               pilot01        69 0.0737
4 divided                1               pilot01        70 0.0748
5 visual_only            1               pilot01        12 0.0128

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq    freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
1 auditory_only          0               pilot02         0 0      
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0               pilot02         1 0.00107
3 bimodal_focus_visual   0               pilot02         2 0.00214
4 divided                0               pilot02        77 0.0823 
5 visual_only            0               pilot02        11 0.0118 

[[4]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq    freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
1 auditory_only          1               pilot02        12 0.0128 
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 1               pilot02        71 0.0759 
3 bimodal_focus_visual   1               pilot02        70 0.0748 
4 divided                1               pilot02        67 0.0716 
5 visual_only            1               pilot02         1 0.00107

[[5]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq    freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
1 auditory_only          0               pilot03         1 0.00107
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0               pilot03         1 0.00107
3 bimodal_focus_visual   0               pilot03         3 0.00321
4 divided                0               pilot03        75 0.0801 
5 visual_only            0               pilot03         0 0      

[[6]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  blockLabel             trial_resp.corr participant  Freq   freq
  <fct>                  <fct>           <fct>       <int>  <dbl>
1 auditory_only          1               pilot03        11 0.0118
2 bimodal_focus_auditory 1               pilot03        71 0.0759
3 bimodal_focus_visual   1               pilot03        69 0.0737
4 divided                1               pilot03        69 0.0737
5 visual_only            1               pilot03        12 0.0128
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could collapse with `as.data.frame`

```
data1 %>% 
  select(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %>% 
  group_by(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant) %$% 
  with(., table(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant))  %>%
  as.data.frame
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that maybe I have to be cleared. Because I need to add a final row for each participant and trial. resp.corr level for sum and a column for frequencies

Comment: I have added edits to my question

Comment: unfortunately I could not upload all the data because of the characters limit, but the aim of the question was too different. Could you please check this better

Comment: @creativity with the update in a list (group_split), what is the expected output

Comment: @creativity regarding creating rows, did you meant `table(mtcars[, c("cyl", "vs", "am")]) %>% apply(MARGIN = 3, addmargins, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. For each of 6 'chunks' of data (obtained with group_split()), I need to add a row with Total, meaning the sum under Freq and freq column

Comment: @creativity YOu can use `%>%group_split(participant, trial_resp.corr) %>% map(adorn_totals)`? i.e. library(janitor)

Comment: @creativity ex.g `table(mtcars[, c("cyl", "vs", "am")]) %>% as.data.frame %>% group_split(cyl, vs) %>% map(janitor::adorn_totals)`

Comment: thank you so much. Actually, the solution which is closer to my idea is the one that you have proposed in your first example. The sum row is ok (sum in the vertical sense). I would not need the one in the horizontal direction, but in place of it, there should be the frequencies (%) and the sum (%) in the last row of that column. Do not know if it is easy to realize this by using mtcars database